# Extracting specific data from hierarchical-data in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, time-series

I have a dataframe made up of 6 columns. Columns 1 to 5 each have discrete names/values, such as a district, year, month, age interval and gender. The sixth column is the number of death counts for that specific combination.

```
               District Gender Year Month Age.Group Total.Deaths
1              Eastern  Female 2003     1        -1            0
2              Eastern  Female 2003     1        -2            2
3              Eastern  Female 2003     1         0            2
4              Eastern  Female 2003     1      01-4            1
5              Eastern  Female 2003     1     05-09            0
6              Eastern  Female 2003     1     10-14            1
7              Eastern  Female 2003     1     15-19            0
8              Eastern  Female 2003     1     20-24            4
9              Eastern  Female 2003     1     25-29            9
10             Eastern  Female 2003     1     30-34            3
11             Eastern  Female 2003     1     35-39            7
12             Eastern  Female 2003     1     40-44            5
13             Eastern  Female 2003     1     45-49            5
14             Eastern  Female 2003     1     50-54            8
15             Eastern  Female 2003     1     55-59            5
16             Eastern  Female 2003     1     60-64            4
17             Eastern  Female 2003     1     65-69            7
18             Eastern  Female 2003     1     70-74            8
19             Eastern  Female 2003     1     75-79            5
20             Eastern  Female 2003     1     80-84           10
21             Eastern  Female 2003     1       85+           11
22             Eastern  Female 2003     2        -1            0
23             Eastern  Female 2003     2        -2            0
24             Eastern  Female 2003     2         0            4
25             Eastern  Female 2003     2      01-4            1
26             Eastern  Female 2003     2     05-09            2
27             Eastern  Female 2003     2     10-14            2
28             Eastern  Female 2003     2     15-19            0
```

I would like to filter, or extract, smaller dataframes from this big dataframe.
For example, I would like to only have four age groups. These four age groups will each contain:

```
Group 0: Consisting of Age.Group -1, -2 and 0.
Group 1-4: Consisting of Age.Group 01-4
Group 5-14: Consisting of Age.Group 05-09 and 10-14
Group 15+: Consisting of Age.Group 15-19 to 85+
```

The `Total.Deaths` will then be the sum for each of these groups.

So I want it to look like this

```
               District Gender Year Month Age.Group Total.Deaths
1              Eastern  Female 2003     1         0            4
2              Eastern  Female 2003     1      01-4            1
3              Eastern  Female 2003     1     05-14            1
4              Eastern  Female 2003     1       15+            104
5              Eastern  Female 2003     2         0            4
6              Eastern  Female 2003     2      01-4            1
7              Eastern  Female 2003     2     05-14            4
8              Eastern  Female 2003     2       15+            ...
```

I have a lot of data and have searched for a few days, but unable to find a function to help be do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a pithier way of recoding your age variable using something like `recode` from the `car` package, particularly since you've conveniently got your current age variable coded with levels that sort nicely as characters. But for only a few levels, I often just recode them by hand by creating a new age variable, and this method is good practice for just 'getting stuff done' in R:

```
#Reading your data in from a text file that I made via copy/paste
dat <- read.table("~/Desktop/soEx.txt",sep="",header=TRUE)

#Make sure Age.Group is ordered and init new age variable
dat$Age.Group <- factor(dat$Age.Group,ordered=TRUE)
dat$AgeGroupNew <- rep(NA,nrow(dat))

#The recoding
dat$AgeGroupNew[dat$Age.Group <= "0"] <- "0"
dat$AgeGroupNew[dat$Age.Group == "01-4"] <- "01-4"
dat$AgeGroupNew[dat$Age.Group >= "05-09" & dat$Age.Group <= "10-14" ] <- "05-14"
dat$AgeGroupNew[dat$Age.Group > "10-14" ] <- "15+"
```

Then we can generate summaries using `ddply` and `summarise`:

```
datNew <- ddply(dat,.(District,Gender,Year,Month,AgeGroupNew),summarise,
            TotalDeaths = sum(Total.Deaths))
```

I was worried at first because I got 91 deaths instead of 104 as you indicated, but I counted by hand and 91 is right I think. A typo, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks so much joran. It's working on my side - and I learned a few R things. Thank you again. Sorry for the 104 typo!